# Python Creating Array with function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying to make this matrix

```
array([[0,1,2],
       [10,11,12],
       [100,101,102],
       [110,111,112]])
```

with this function

```
def f(x,y):
   if x < 2:
      return 10 * x + y
   else :
      return 100 + 10 * x + 6
```

and

```
print(np.fromfunction(f,(4,3),dtype=int)
```

However, this gave me a error

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I think `x` doesn't mean exact row that I've meant to use.

How can I fix this function to get the result above and can I know what the problem is?

Comment: Please check your post, it's not executable as python code.

Comment: Yes, I have an error for this one.. I want to know what the meaning of x that I described. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: Is this the output you want? `array([[0,10,100,110], [1,11,101,111], [2,12,102,112]])`

Comment: yes that is what I want Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def f(i,j):
    return np.where(i<2, i*10+j, 100+j+10*(i-2)  )

print np.fromfunction(f ,(4,3),dtype=int)
```

output:

```
[[  0   1   2]
 [ 10  11  12]
 [100 101 102]
 [110 111 112]]
```

`np.where` returns the individual element rather than the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

```
f,(4,3) clear comma after "f".
```

Comment: make it more explanatory so that others can also understand

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this isn't working is that fromfunction is passing to its first argument array objects and not int.

The code complains because `a < 2` is a array / int comparison, you should run `a.all() < 2`

The working code becomes :

```
from numpy import fromfunction

def f(x,y):
   if x.all() < 2:
      return 10 * x + y
   else :
      return 100 + 10 * x + 6

print fromfunction(f,(3,3),dtype=int)
```

Comment: output: [[ 0  1  2]
 [10 11 12]
 [20 21 22]]